# Dealing with bad character UTF 8 python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, utf-8

How to print and read encoding utf-8 file without bad character, I'm using pycharm and python 3.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import sys

sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

place = pd.read_csv('country.csv', encoding='utf-8', chunksize=13000000, error_bad_lines=False, squeeze= True)
for chunk in place:
    place_list = chunk['name'].tolist()
    print(u"{}".format(place_list))
```

**country.csv**

```
name,
T’Kareseskop
Gröll Seamount
Pinzón Knoll
Pinar del Río Knoll
Piñones Canyon
```

output:

```
Tâ€™Kareseskop
GrÃ¶ll Seamount
PinzÃ³n Knoll
Pinar del RÃ­o Knoll
PiÃ±ones Canyon
```

expected output:

```
T’Kareseskop
Gröll Seamount
Pinzón Knoll
Pinar del Río Knoll
Piñones Canyon
```

I'm using chunk because `country.csv` is a large file

Answer (score 0):

calling `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` will not reconfigure your terminal program (the "cmd" window),  it will just force Python to output utf-8, even though the terminal configuration differs.

If when you remove this call, you don't get the correct characters it is because Python is not finding the correct terminal encoding automatically. But it, obviously, is not utf-8.

Maybe, better than trying to tweak the ancient windows terminal, is to install a nicer terminal than the arcane "cmd" - check this one: https://cmder.net/ (I suppose it is windows, because all Linux distributions and Mac OS do use utf-8 by default for several years now)

Comment: Thanks! Actually my goal is how to get array output from file using chunk pandas. I want it to print exactly like the country.csv file is but ends up with bad character

Comment: the kind of character replacements you are showing is typical from when Python sends the output in utf-8, but the mean actually displaying the characters is using a charmap like latin1 - then, characters that take 2 btes in utf-8 end up showing as 2 characters on that display.